# ObjectInputStream reading incorrectly

Tags: java, file-io, javax.imageio, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a question about why i am getting the outputs i am on this code. I have a bigger project i am working on but I narrowed the problem down to this. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {

static String workingDirectory;

static int num1;
static int num2;
static BufferedImage image1;
static BufferedImage image2;

public static final int JOB = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/";

    if(JOB == 0){
        read(workingDirectory + "output&input.myExtention");
    }else if(JOB == 1){
        num1 = 18;
        num2 = 100;
        getImages("Smile.jpeg", "Frown.jpeg");
        write(workingDirectory + "output&input.myEx");
    }

}

static void getImages(String imageName1, String imageName2){
    try{
        image1 = ImageIO.read(new File(workingDirectory + imageName1));
        image2 = ImageIO.read(new File(workingDirectory + imageName2));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void read(String path){
    File file = new File(path);

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        num1 = ois.readInt();
        System.out.println("Num1 = " + num1);

        image1 = ImageIO.read(ois);
        System.out.println("Image1 = " + image1);

        num2 = ois.readInt();
        System.out.println("Num2 = " + num2);

        image2 = ImageIO.read(ois);
        System.out.println("Image2 = " + image2);

        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void write(String path){
    File file = new File(path);

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        System.out.println("Writing Num1 = " + num1);
        oos.writeInt(num1);
        System.out.println("Image1 = " + image1);
        ImageIO.write(image1, "png", oos);
        System.out.println("Writing Num2 = " + num2);
        oos.writeInt(num2);
        System.out.println("Image2 = " + image2);
        ImageIO.write(image2, "png", oos);

        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And here is the output on two different runs. The first I set JOB = 1 (writing the file) and for the second I set JOB = 0 (reading the file).

```
OUTPUT 1:

Writing Num1 = 18
Image1 = BufferedImage@77827284: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@152c7568 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 225 height = 225 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
Writing Num2 = 100
Image2 = BufferedImage@16ba8602: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@152c7568 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 225 height = 225 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2


OUTPUT 2:

Num1 = 18
Image1 = BufferedImage@4d865b28: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@2fcac6db transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 225 height = 225 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
Num2 = -1974494307
Image2 = null
```

What I'm wondering is why I am getting different readings than what I wrote and why do images read as null after the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `png` is not a Java `java.lang.Object` (e.g. a raw byte sequence doesn't encode a length and byte arrays are not dynamically sized in Java they are `java.lang.Object`s). Therefore, one solution is to wrap your (`ImageIO.write(image1, "png", oos);` [and the second image write] and then the read calls) with a `byte[]`. Allow me to illustrate, that is something like -

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image1, "png", baos); 
oos.writeObject(baos.toByteArray());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image2, "png", baos2); 
oos.writeObject(baos2.toByteArray());
```

and then update your read (that is) -

```
image1 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[])ois.readObject()));
image2 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[])ois.readObject()));
```

Comment: A png when written with `ImageIO.write()` is a sequence of bytes. In the OP's code, `ImageIO` writes directly to the `ObjectOutputStream` using one of the `write()` methods. There may be a reason why that doesn't work, or more correctly why it doesn't read back correctly via `ImageIO.read()`, but you haven't given it.

Comment: If it needs to encode a length, that's what your answer should say, not 'a PNG is not a Java object', which isn't an explanation by itself.

Comment: Have to agree with @EJP. The problem is that the ImageIO reader plugin will read as few bytes as needed, probably less than what the writer originally wrote. You need to encode the length of the image, to make sure the stream is properly aligned after the image read. And the OP probably shouldn't use an `ObjectInputStream` or `writeObject()` in the first place..